# TCP Retranmissions with Redis and Nodejs

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, tcp, node.js, redis

Recently we started using LogicMonitor. It reported a number of issue we were not aware of and they have all been actual minor to moderate issues.

One issue we have is TCP Retranmissions on our Core Production Server at or near 100%. This is a windows 2012 server running Redis and Nodejs. The retranmissions are seen by netstat but they are not seen by WireShark. WireShark shows at most 0.5 to 1%. This issue is seen on both our Live Production server and our test server which has 0 traffic going to it except when we are testing a patch.

The question is, is this a false positive since they are not hitting the wire or should we be concerned? I didn't believe the number when I first saw it in LogicMonitor but no other server except for Production and Test have this issue and I have confirmed the numbers with netstat.

Note: I've done a little digging and the Nodejs server appears to be talking to Redis via socket.io.

Comment: This appears to be a false positive. I install npcap and captured the traffic on the loopback. The node app is sending Redis a keep alive packet every 100ms give or take on each connection with there being 9 of them. Windows seems to be seeing this repeat traffic as retranmissions. Over a 10 min period 1 million keep alives were sent. Seems crazy to me and have brought it up with the vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False positive - frequent keep alive messages appeared as retransmissions in netstat/wmi on windows 2012 server.